# Product items is not iterable from models

Tags: django

I want to show all my objects that are in my models to the page that i have created

all the code is given below,
thanks
models.py---->>

```
 from django.db import models

 from django.utils import timezone

 class Product(models.Model):
     title      = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
     description = models.TextField(blank = False)
     price      = models.IntegerField()
     datecreated = models.TimeField()
     featured   = models.BooleanField(default = False)



     def __str__(self):
        return self.title


     def get_Absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("products", kwargs = {"id":self.id})
```

views.py---->>

```
def home(request):
             obj = Product.objects.get()
             context = {
                     "obj":obj
                        }
             return render(request, "firstapp/home.html", context)
```

templates---->>

```
<h1>Products in database</h1>
            {% for x in obj %}
                <p>{{x.title}}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

getting error model objects are not iterable

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.all()` to get all objects from model.
Try this:

```
obj = Product.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

You here write:

```
obj = Product.objects.get()
```

This means that you fetch a *single* `Product` object. This call will *only* succeed if the `Product` table contains exactly one record, and the result is that `obj` is a `Product`, *not* a collection of `Product`s.

Unless you have implemented an `__iter__`  function on your `Product` (strictly speaking you *can* do that, but it might not be a very good idea), you thus can *not* iterate over a single `Product` object, and hence the program fails. You can however fetch a `QuerySet` of `Product`s and iterate over that `QuerySet`.

You likely want to fetch *all* `Product`s:

```
def home(request):
    obj = Product.objects.all()
    context = { 'obj': obj }
    return render(request, 'firstapp/home.html', context)
```

In case you want to fetch a single `Product`, your path should probably contain the primary key, slug, or another way to identify the product.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to filter the objects you can  use .filter() to get filter the objects from model.
obj = Product.objects.filter()